# Erlang return value conventions

Tags: coding-style, code-quality, coding-standards, code-formatting, erlang

Should functions that return tuples, always return tuples?

For example, I have a function `is_user_name_allowed` that returns a tuple in this he form if the username is not allowed:

`{false, ["Reason 1","Reason 2"]}`

If the I want to return true, is there any convention/benefit to returning a tuple as opposed to simply returning `true`? (`{true}` vs `true`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is to just use `true` in this case. The same style is used in many OTP libraries, e.g. [`lists:keyfind/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3).

Comment: This answer maybe shorter, but I like that you mentioned the OTP libraries, since it seems their styling is generally the "standard convention". It sealed the deal for me skipping the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You may save some time and memory by not having to construct and evaluate a tuple if you just return a bare-naked atom.  Write a benchmark, run several million of each way through it and you'll know for sure.

That aside, it doesn't really matter:

```
handle_result(true) -> do_true_things();
handle_result({false, Reasons}) -> do_false_things(Reasons).

some_function() -> handle_result(is_user_name_allowed("bob")).
```

The first version of the function would work just the same if it was specified as `handle_result({true})` and `is_user_name_allowed()` returned a tuple.

More important is the safety aspect.  Make sure you use the matcher to handle the result, which will give you an implicit check that it was valid without having to do it after each call.  If something goes wrong, a `function_clause` error will bring it to your attention.

What I would *not* do is return a tuple that's always structured the same way:

```
{true, []}
{false, ["Ugly", "Mother dresses him funny"]}
```

While you could match them, it leaves open the possibility that a caller will do...

```
{Result, Reasons} = is_user_name_allowed("bob")
```

...and not validate the result.

Comment: I was going to mention, performance shouldn't be a consideration here. I figured that at best choosing one over the other for performance reasons would be premature optimization, I'm just focused on the style here

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix:  The performance point wasn't actually intended to be up top; in editing it fell out that way.  But it is something to consider if you're writing an API that may see very heavy use in the future.